# activemq-cpp receive timeout when the message send to the queue with property timetolive

Tags: timeout, activemq-cpp

I send a message to the queue with property "timetolive" with activemq producer and then receive with activemq consumer function receive(long long timeout).After receive some messages the receive always timeout and cannot receive any messages again.

It is work well when the message not have property timetolive.

why ,and how can I do when receive timeout.

Version
Activemq 5.4.2
activemq-cpp 3.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you messages are exceeding you TTL value then the receive calls won't return anything.  You either need to set a longer TTL, or ensure that the clocks are synced on your client and server machines.  Otherwise you need to provide more info here to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks very much. The problem has been resolved. As you said, I sync the clocks on my client and server machines, and client return to work normal.

Comment: If this is resolved make sure you mark this thread as answered so others no there is a solution.  Thanks.